# Why is formatting broken when using bootstrap in PHP?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to generate Bootstrap 5 table `.table-striped` using data from MySQL, table: [users]

The table in plain HTML looks fine, but as soon as I generate it using PHP all styling disappears

PHP Code:

```
 <?php

$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC");

echo "<table class='table table-striped'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Rank</th>
<th>Created at</th>
</tr>
</thead>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tbody>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['rank'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['created_at'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo " </tbody>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

and I have `<div class='table-responsive'>` before `<?php` and `</div>` after `?>`

I would be glad if you could explain me where I am making a mistake and I would like the table to have the same styling as in pure HTML

EDIT:

rendered HTML

```
<div class='table-responsive'>
<table class='table table-striped'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Rank</th>
<th>Created at</th>
</tr>
</thead><tbody><tr><td>39</td><td></td><td>julia</td><td>2021-12-20 00:42:14</td></tr> </tbody><tbody><tr><td>40</td><td>test</td><td>user</td><td>2021-12-20 02:35:37</td></tr> </tbody><tbody><tr><td>41</td><td>testt</td><td>user</td><td>2021-12-20 17:22:43</td></tr> </tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: Post the rendered HTML please

Comment: Do you add styles link too or is it full content?

Comment: @Justinas I think this is all suppose to be one section though so should only be one body.

Comment: `Use .table-striped to add zebra-striping to any table row within the <tbody>.` By wrapping each row in its own tbody, you're resetting the striping. [src](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#striped-rows)

Comment: @user3783243 I moved `while` behind `<tbody>` and fixed that, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are building a new `tbody` for every row. You should move the `tbody` creation outside the `while` loop. You also only need 1 `echo`, rather than `echo`ing every line. I would do:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC");
$output = "<div class='table-responsive'>
<table class='table table-striped'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th style='background-color:#ad8c70'>#</th>
<th style='background-color:#ad8c70'>Username</th>
<th style='background-color:#ad8c70'>Rank</th>
<th style='background-color:#ad8c70'>Created at</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbdoy>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$output .= "<tr>
<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['rank'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['created_at'] . "</td>
</tr>";
}
mysqli_close($link);
$output .= '</tbody></table>';
echo $output;
?>
```